# Permission denied for accessing to data/data file in android

Tags: android

My mobile phone is Huawei u8510 and I use Eclipse to develop my android project. With Eclipse, in DDMS->File Explorer, I cannot see any database file in data/data directory. 
Therefore, I try to use ADB Shell for accessing the database file, so I open cmd and go to **\android-sdk\platform-tools** directory. Then, I type **adb shell**, then with **su**. But I get error "Permission Denied".

Please help me, how can I access to database.

Best Regards

Comment: Which database you want to access, android's default sqlite ? or something else.

Comment: and you want to see the database which you created, right?

Comment: If you are using a Real Device and it is not rooted then it is not possible to see you data base in FileExplorer because due to some security reason that folder is locked in android system. and if you are using it in a emulator you will find it in FileExplorer /data/data/your package name/databases/yourdatabse.db

Comment: or check this also, http://blog.kwyps.com/2011/07/how-to-view-sqlite-database-on-your.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are debugging or running your application through your device you will not be able to see your database in DDMS and if you are debugging  or running it through emulator and still not able to see database then it might be that your databse is not created due to some error in Database class.Please debug it properely to get the required solution.